# How to plot a "line of best fit" with a point that is not in the current dataframe?

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression, scatter-plot, prediction

I am graphing cricket chirps per second occurring in relation to temperature.

I am graphing the line of best fit through the scatterplot of data points and now I need to plot the prediction of a cricket that has chirped 19 times in a second. How do I plot the prediction with the original data including the line of best fit?

Please note that 19 chirps per second is not in the data set and is a prediction. I know that I need to create a temp variable and that I can find the temperature by:

19 = slope * temperature + intercept

which comes to:

temperature = 91.113.

I can plot a graph with a line if I include another point from the data set, but it is not the line of best fit( which is what i need ).

Here is the code I have plotting the line of best fit, without predicting 19 chirps per second.Please pay attention to the second block of code, as this is the portion of code that I need to adjust to create the prediction. The first bit of code is just so you have everything I have. Pulled from Google Colab:

## 1

```
!pip install xlrd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel('https://college.cengage.com/mathematics/brase/understandable_statistics/7e/students/datasets/slr/excel/slr02.xls')
df = df.rename(columns={'X':'chirps_per_sec', 'Y':'temperature'})
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(df['chirps_per_sec'], df['temperature'])
plt.xlabel("chirps_per_sec")
plt.ylabel("temperature")
import random
a = np.ones(15, dtype=np.int64, order='C')
df['ones'] = a
X = df[['ones', 'temperature']].as_matrix()
Y = df['chirps_per_sec'].as_matrix().reshape(-1, 1)
X_transpose = np.transpose(X) 
X_transpose_X = np.matmul(X_transpose, X)
inverse = np.linalg.inv(X_transpose_X)
identity = np.matmul(inverse, X_transpose_X)
Y_X_transpose= np.matmul(X_transpose, Y)
beta = np.matmul(inverse, Y_X_transpose)
```

## 2

```
beta=np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(np.matmul(np.transpose(X), X)), np.matmul(np.transpose(X), Y))
print(beta)
beta_0 = beta[0,0]
beta_1 = beta[1,0]
plt.scatter(df['temperature'], df['chirps_per_sec'])
axes = plt.gca()
x_vals = np.array(axes.get_xlim())
y_vals = beta_0 + beta_1 * x_vals
plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals, '-', color='b')
plt.ylabel('chirps_per_sec')
plt.xlabel('temperature')
plt.show()
```

The url for the image of what code block two renders, without the prediction of 19 chirps per second:
[graph of cricket chirps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnlg1.jpg)

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Since you already have the fit parameters (intercept and slope), you can just compute the x value corresponding to `y=19` and plot that point standalone as following. This way, you don't include it in the fit but just use the fitted model to predict it.

```
y_point = 19
x_point = (y_point - beta_0)/beta_1 # --> This is 91.113

plt.scatter(x_point, y_point, marker='x', color='b', s=100)
```